# How can I make an string form an array?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-collection

I create an array with output:

```
#items: array:3 [▼
    0 => array:4 [▼
      0 => "2019-11-23"
      1 => 5
      2 => "5"
      3 => "5"
    ]
    1 => array:4 [▼
      0 => "2019-11-24"
      1 => "12"
      2 => "0"
      3 => "0"
    ]
```

now i what to have in one row all values from [1] like: `$value = [5, 12]`
i tried to do this with a foreach loop, i get the value's but i down know how to put them together like above desired example ( `$value = [5, 12]` )

Comment: What's the expected output from this array?

Comment: `$value = '5','12'` is not a valid syntax

Comment: Sorry; i my desired/expected output should look like $value = [5, 12]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have data assigned to Laravel collection (and it seems you have them in collection) like this:

```
$data = collect([
    [
        "2019-11-23",
        5,
        "5",
        "5",
    ],
    [
        "2019-11-24",
        "12",
        "0",
        "0",
    ],
]);
```

When you use:

```
$result = $data->pluck('1')->all();
```

you will get:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => 5
  1 => "12"
]
```

and if you need to cast all values to integers you can use:

```
$result = array_map('intval', $data->pluck('1')->all());
```

and the result will be

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => 5
  1 => 12
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php):

```php
$originalArray = [
    ["2019-11-23", 5, "5", "5"],
    ["2019-11-24", "12", "0", "0"],
]

$outputArray = array_map(function($value) {
    return $value[1]; 
}, $originalArray);
```